# same query gets slower after other queries get called (using a lot of prepared statements inside stored procedures)

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I have a query that, when i run it first after i restart mysql, takes 2 seconds, but when I run a sequence of other queries before it (this query belongs to a procedure between other procedures) suddenly the query takes around 2 minutes, If i restart mysql and rerun it it takes again 2 seconds.

The durations are almost the same (~2 seconds and ~ 2 minutes) so even when it slows down it's not random, and it's specifically this query that gets slower (or maybe this table), everything else is normal.

- Disabled `query_cache`
- increased `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (I assumed it had to do with a memory or a buffer getting full making the next query slower)
- checked lock tables

I don't know what else (except the data) can a query affect another query/table after it.

Is there any path to search for or something to try, I don't have any lead on what to search for.

---

I'm using MySQL version 5.7

the explain plan is

[image]

I actually found out that the issue is not with a specific table, but simply too many prepared statements

```
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| Com_prepare_sql    | 60    |
| Com_stmt_prepare   | 82    |
| Com_xa_prepare     | 0     |
| Com_stmt_reprepare | 24    |
+--------------------+-------+
```

It is mentionned in the doc that 
`A prepared statement is also global to the session. If you create a prepared statement within a stored routine, it is not deallocated when the stored routine ends.`

I thought this meant that they should be deallocated explicitely, but apparently this is not the case.

```
insert into s__demand_table_14_0(year, hospital_id, disease_id, nb_patients)
        SELECT fcbf_parent.year,
           table_referral.to_hospital_id,
           table_referral.disease_id,
           SUM(ifnull(fcbf_parent.nb_patients, 0) *
               ifnull(table_referral.ratio_of_referrals * (1 + ifnull(ir.ratio_of_referrals, 0)), 0)) +
           ifnull(SUM(fcbf.nb_patients), 0) AS referred_patients
    FROM table_hospital bf_current
             join table_hospital bf_parent on bf_parent.type = ? or bf_parent.type = ?
             LEFT JOIN
         table_referral ON bf_current.type = ? and table_referral.to_hospital_id = bf_current.id and table_referral.from_hospital_id = bf_parent.id
            JOIN s__demand_catchment_by_hospital_14_0 fcbf_parent on
            fcbf_parent.disease_id = table_referral.disease_id
            and fcbf_parent.hospital_id = bf_parent.id
            and fcbf_parent.nb_patients > 0
             LEFT JOIN s__demand_catchment_by_hospital_14_0 fcbf on
            fcbf.disease_id = table_referral.disease_id
            and fcbf.hospital_id = bf_current.id
             left join s__intermediate_referral_14_0 ir
                       on (ir.from_hospital_type = ? OR ir.from_hospital_type = ?) and
                          ir.to_hospital_type = ? and ir.year = fcbf_parent.year and ir.disease_id = table_referral.disease_id
    where bf_current.type = ?
    GROUP BY fcbf_parent.year, table_referral.to_hospital_id, table_referral.disease_id;
```

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'com_%_sql';`

```
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| Com_dealloc_sql | 25    |
| Com_execute_sql | 76    |
| Com_prepare_sql | 50    |
+-----------------+-------+


 SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'com_stmt_%';
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| Com_stmt_execute        | 100   |
| Com_stmt_close          | 48    |
| Com_stmt_fetch          | 0     |
| Com_stmt_prepare        | 74    |
| Com_stmt_reset          | 0     |
| Com_stmt_send_long_data | 0     |
| Com_stmt_reprepare      | 24    |
+-------------------------+-------+
```

RAM is not changing drastically

Explain Plan

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                                    | key                                              | key_len | ref                                            | rows  | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bf_parent     | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,base_facili_type_6d98f9_idx                                                                                                                                                                              | base_facili_type_6d98f9_idx                      | 257     | const                                          |     1 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fcbf_parent   | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                             | NULL                                             | NULL    | NULL                                           | 19142 |     3.33 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | base_referral | NULL       | ref    | referral_disease_id_ad6e6e71_fk_disease_icd_code,referral_from_facility_id_b9840c9f_fk_facility_id,referral_to_facility_id_81a49e98_fk_facility_id,base_referr_disease_b74959_idx,base_referr_disease_9bbdaf_idx | referral_disease_id_ad6e6e71_fk_disease_icd_code | 257     | capacity_planning.fcbf_parent.disease_id       |     3 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bf_current    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,base_facili_type_6d98f9_idx                                                                                                                                                                              | PRIMARY                                          | 4       | capacity_planning.base_referral.to_facility_id |     1 |    57.14 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fcbf          | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                             | NULL                                             | NULL    | NULL                                           | 19142 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ir            | NULL       | ALL    | forecast_intermediat_disease_id_689b0572_fk_disease_i                                                                                                                                                            | NULL                                             | NULL    | NULL                                           |     1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: MySQL version? What query? EXPLAIN query? Table structures (`show create table tblname`? How do your stored procedures change the same data as your query? What is the MySQL [profile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html) of the query for both your cases.

Comment: I updated my question with these info

Comment: Maybe when you execute this select after the updates, the engine has to write a lot of dirty pages to disk. You can check that this is the case by setting innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0. This way the dirty pages will be written directly to disk (making updates take longer). If this is the case you may want to tune your engine by setting appropriate innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct and innodb_buffer_pool_size numbers according to your requirements,

Comment: Just tried what you said, and still have the same issue  `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0` in my.cnf didn't make any noticeable difference

Comment: Please show us the query!  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  How slow are the `UPDATEs`?  How big is the table(s)?  How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: I updated the question with the query, this query is taking 3 min....and sometimes a couple of seconds, i tried changing innodb_buffer_pool_size between 1G, 2G and 6G ... all same result

Comment: There are still several unanswered questions in the Comments.

Comment: @DanyY Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'com_%_sql' and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'com_stmt_%'; C) RAM on the server.  com_dealloc_sql and com_stmt_close counts are your responsibility to release resources after being used.  Yes prepared statements may be reused but should not be left hanging for extended period of time.

Comment: @DanyY Please post A) the real query and B) complete text of EXPLAIN.  I think we all agree, using temporary, filesort and Block Nexted Loop techniques should be avoided when possible to conserve resources.

Comment: Sorry, lost a little hope on this :D. ok i updated my question with your requests. 
`filesort and Block Nexted Loop techniques should be avoided when possible to conserve resources.` I didnt' understand what you mean by this.
Thanks a lot

Comment: The two `EXPLAINs` seem to be different; please explain.

Comment: @RickJames it's because i'm always trying to make changes to the query to see some differences, but the numbers in the explain are not huge to explain the 3 min, and the issue is not (or seems not) just in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to reduce the time dramatically by doing these 3 steps:

- removed excess of indexes
- remove autocommit, foreign key checks and unique checks at the beginning of each procedure
- Changing storage engine of the tables i'm filling to MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

Your com_prepare_sql was 50, com_dealloc_sql was 25, meaning you have left RESOURCES in USE because the CLOSE() has not signaled you have completed the process.

Your com_stmt_prepare was 72, com_stmt_close was 48, meaning you have left RESOURCES in USE because the CLOSE() has not signaled you have completed the process.

Consistent query execution speed is more likely to be achieved when the dealloc and close counts are closer to the respective prepared counts.

General Log capture and analysis will confirm the resources were left in use and not deallocated or closed.

Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile that includes FREE Utility Scripts and contact info.